# Enforce tests run before TFS check in

Tags: tfs, build, integrated

Does anyone know how to enforce that all tests pass before a TFS check in?

Comment: hey, it can be done by defining a Check in policy in TFS.

Comment: @Hansmukh. I'm curious. How would you do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TFS provides so-called *Gated check-ins*. That means: the complete build (which includes the test runs) is run and has to pass, otherwise the check-in is rejected. It's quite performance-demanding and somewhat time-consuming, when working in a larger team, but otherwise works like a charm.

HTH.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the default "Testing checkin policy".

If you want to create your own testing policy, you can use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jimlamb/how-to-implement-package-and-deploy-custom-check-in-policy-for-tfs-2010).